# No Response on Dell XPS-13 2-in-1 Touch Screen; What Can I Run to Diagnose?

Tags: dell, touchscreen, xps

I am unable to get any response from my touch screen on my Dell XPS 13 2-in-1 (2020). It works fine on Windows (using Windows 10) but doesn't respond to any touch-events with Ubuntu booted.

From hostnamectl I get, among some machine and boot ID info [redacted], the following:

```
           Chassis: convertible
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-52-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

When I run xinput --list it returns the following:

```
      
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

From v4l2-ctl --list-devices I get the following:

```
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
```

When I run sudo v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0
I get:

```
Identified face as [my local username]
```

This one is clearly the camera

When I run the same command on each of the other three video devices (video1-video3); I receive no response from the terminal at all and nothing happens wrt the touch screen (icons and windows don't respond to touch events etc).

It is not listed anywhere under libinput list-devices (output available upon request, though)
It does not respond after running libinput-debug-events nor are any events logged when touching the screen

Running evtest yields the following:

```
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Lid Switch
/dev/input/event1:  Power Button
/dev/input/event2:  Sleep Button
/dev/input/event3:  AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event4:  SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
/dev/input/event5:  Dell WMI hotkeys
/dev/input/event6:  Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate
/dev/input/event7:  Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate
/dev/input/event8:  HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic
```

(The SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad has been confirmed to be my actual onboard mouse TouchPad and not the touch screen)

sudo lshw yields typical hardware lshw info but nothing that looked useful / no mention of a touch screen; I can include it if it helps anyone (it's an extensive dump so I left it out, here)

Finally, I followed the instructions in the self-answer from here; modprobe did not appear to enable the touch screen: https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/Touchscreen-on-XPS13-7390-2-in-1-in-Ubuntu/td-p/7393023

Any ideas of what I can try next to allow the OS to communicate with the touch screen? Thank you in advance